# Can't display text column when split text into associated table

Tags: python, regex, pandas, text

Here's my dataset, (only one column)

```
Apr 1 09:14:55 i have apple
Apr 2 08:10:10 i have mango
```

There's the result I need

```
month  date      time       message
Apr    1     09:14:55  i have apple
Apr    2     09:10:10  i have mango
```

This is what I've done

```
import pandas as pd

month = []
date = []
time = []
message = []

for line in dns_data:
   month.append(line.split()[0])
   date.append(line.split()[1])
   time.append(line.split()[2])

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'month': month, 'date':date, 'time':time})
```

This is the output I get

```
    month     date      time
0     Apr     1     09:14:55
1     Apr     2     09:10:10
```

How to display `message` column?

Comment: `df1 = df['data'].str.extract(r'^(?P<month>\S+)\s+(?P<date>\d+)\s+(?P<time>\S+)\s+(?P<message>.*)')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameter `n` in [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for spliting by first 3 whitespaces, `expand=True` is for output `DataFrame`:

```
print (df)
                           col
0  Apr 1 09:14:55 i have apple
1  Apr 2 08:10:10 i have mango

df1 = df['col'].str.split(n=3, expand=True)
df1.columns=['month','date','time','message']
print (df1)
  month date      time       message
0   Apr    1  09:14:55  i have apple
1   Apr    2  08:10:10  i have mango
```

Another solution with list comprehension:

```
c = ['month','date','time','message']
df1 = pd.DataFrame([x.split(maxsplit=3) for x in df['col']], columns=c)
print (df1)
  month date      time       message
0   Apr    1  09:14:55  i have apple
1   Apr    2  08:10:10  i have mango
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Series.str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) with a regex pattern:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': {0: 'Apr 1 09:14:55 i have apple', 1: 'Apr 2 08:10:10 i have mango'}})
df_new = (df.text.str
          .extractall(r'^(?P<month>\w{3})\s?(?P<date>\d{1,2})\s?(?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s?(?P<message>.*)$')
          .reset_index(drop=True))
print(df_new)

  month date      time       message
0   Apr   1  09:14:55  i have apple
1   Apr   2  08:10:10  i have mango
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
(?<Month>\w+)\s(?<Date>\d+)\s(?<Time>[\w:]+)\s(?<Message>.*)

Match 1
Month   Apr
Date    1
Time    09:14:55
Message i have apple
Match 2
Month   Apr
Date    2
Time    08:10:10
Message i have mango
```

https://rubular.com/r/1S4BcbDxPtlVxE